Outside Faucet ON with Split Hose Attachment CLOSED
I accidentally opened my outside hose all the way with the hose splitter valves both closed. Did pressure build up in the line and cause leaks in my pipes? It was about 2 minutes.

Are there pipes leaking?

Do you have pipes leaking?  Do you see water dripping anywhere?  Opening a hose bib with an attached splitter closed should do nothing to any pipes. The pressure did not increase.  You may be worried about nothing.

It just moved the full water pressure about an inch or two to the splitter valves.  When you open those valves, the pressure will move to the end of the hose.  It is the hose that might be a concern, since most are not made to keep full water pressure in them for long periods.

The pipes do not care where the water is shut off.
Pressure in the pipes is exactly the same if it is shut off at an interior shutoff valve, spigot, a splitter screwed into the spigot or the nozzle on a hose.  Pressure does not build up, it reaches the maximum and stops.
